# Any way to use a class extension method to support an interface method in C#?

Tags: c#

Console app below compiles, but the interface cast fails at run time.  Is there an easy way to make this work?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Monkey
    {
        public string Shock { get { return "Monkey has been shocked."; } }
    }

    static class MonkeyExtensionToSupportIWombat
    {
        public static string ShockTheMonkey( this Monkey m )
        {
            return m.Shock;
        }
    }

    interface IWombat
    {
        string ShockTheMonkey();
    }

    class Program
    {

        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            var monkey = new Monkey();
            Console.WriteLine( "Shock the monkey without the interface: {0}", monkey.Shock );
            IWombat wombat = monkey as IWombat;
            Console.WriteLine( "Shock the monkey with the interface: {0}", wombat.ShockTheMonkey() );
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't Monkey implement IWombat?

Comment: OK, so you want to extend a sealed class.  Have you considered a wrapper class?  Google/SO should have plenty of examples of them.

Comment: Yeah, sure, that's what I'll have to do.  Wanted to avoid a wrapper / creating that new object every time.

Comment: I think this will work as you expect (the extension method adding a syntactically sugary new method to your Monkey class) but I know it won't work like you think it will so long as you keep trying to use the interface.  Extension methods can be used with interfaces but work just fine extending classes as well.

Answer (score 3):

A Monkey is not derived from IWombat, so I'm not sure why you'd expect that to work (outside of using Reflection or a dynamic call, but that'd be spackling over a basic deficiency in the class design).
If you wanted this to work, you'd have to have Monkey implement IWombat or have another class that inherits from Monkey that implements IWombat (as seen below).

```
class Monkey
{
    public string Shock { get { return "Monkey has been shocked."; } }
}

static class MonkeyExtensionToSupportIWombat
{
    public static string ShockTheMonkey(this Monkey m)
    {
        return m.Shock;
    }
}

interface IWombat
{
    string ShockTheMonkey();
}

class MonkeyBat : Monkey, IWombat
{
    #region IWombat Members

    public string ShockTheMonkey()
    {
        return this.Shock;
    }

    #endregion
}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var monkey = new Monkey();
        Console.WriteLine("Shock the monkey without the interface: {0}", monkey.Shock);

        var monkeyBat = new MonkeyBat();
        Console.WriteLine("Shock the monkey with the interface: {0}", monkeyBat.ShockTheMonkey());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: See my comment to Jim's answer for why I don't want to do this.

Comment: @dudeNumber4: that extra information up front would have been really helpful.  Extension methods on IEnumerable<T> work just fine; have you run into a problem using them?

Comment: The extension methods themselves work fine, but the extension class itself can't support an interface (my original snippet should've read "static class MonkeyExtensionToSupportIWombat: IWombat").  That won't compile b/c a static class can't support an interface.
I'm forced to create a wrapper for List<MyEntity> which sucks b/c we're already using extension methods on List<MyEntity> and it sort of breaks the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The cast will always fail as Monkey does not implement IWombat. But that has nohting to do with extension methods. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I meant the declaration of MonkeyExtensionToSupportIWombat to support IWombat.  That causes compile error.  That's what I would like to be able to do - have Monkey support IWombat by adding the interface method to the extension class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on extension methods, but I think what you're trying to do is the programming equivalent of mixing metaphors. Extension methods basically were introduced so that someone w/out access to the source of a class could expand the functionality of the class. By saying something implements an interface, you're basically saying that you *do have access* to the source, and so there really should be no need for the extension method. If as the designer of a class, you want the consumer of that class to specify functionality, perhaps having Monkey.ShockTheMonkey call a delegate would be more appropriate?

Also, a [Wombat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wombat) is not a [Monkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey) and a Monkey is not a Wombat. Your knowledge of zoology definitely needs some help ;).

Comment: The real reason I don't want to modify the "original" class is because it isn't defined at all - it's a generic list.  Using MVC, we're already using extension methods on lists of various entities.  I wanted to follow that pattern here rather than create some wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

The cast fails because Monkey does not implement IWombat. The cast will always fail.

It looks like he is trying to be able to use the methods on the interface with out actually implementing the interface. In the purest sense, this is not possible. They may be some hackery to get it work though but I dont think it is worth it.